# What is the need of utf-8 encoding for things such as socket communication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, utf-8, socket.io

I am using nodejs as my backend, and sockets for a texting part of my application. I researched about using sockets and came across an interesting fact.

The data being transferred by a socket(in my case a string) has to be utf-8 encoded. What is this utf-8 encoding used for, and why is it needed?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Could you please try to be more empathetic towards new members? Remember when you were new to programming? His questions was not about what is utf8 but why it needs to be specified.

Comment: You know how computers communicate? With bits. If you group bits together you can represent a number. Then everyone can translate a number into text, for example 65 = A.There is a table for that,called ASCII. There A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and some punctuation characters are defined. If you want to send something else, like üåäö, € or  you need something other than ASCII: You need Unicode. But Unicode characters can be 32 bits long. That is a wast of space. UTF-8 encodes the whole range in as few bytes as possible.

Comment: Oh thank you so much man!  So basically i have i got this right? UTF-8 encodes text (as computers communicate through bites), and to avoid space usage use utf-8, and you should use UTF-8 whilst sending strings of data(like a text message) on a socket right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ..The data being transferred by a socket ... has to be utf-8 encoded..

This is not fully true.

A socket can only transfer bytes and therefore it needs to get bytes. A string is not a sequence of bytes but a sequence of characters. To transfer a string over a socket it needs to be represented as a sequence of bytes first and decoded back after transfer. If you already have bytes (like a binary representation of an image) no additional encoding and decoding is needed.

There are various ways of how characters can be represented as bytes, the "character encoding". UTF-8 is one of these encodings where English characters take only a single byte, most characters from western languages take at most 2 bytes etc. There are other encodings like UTF-32 where all characters take 4 bytes or ISO-8859-15 where all characters take one byte only but which can only represent the characters found in western languages.

Because of the small overhead for western languages UTF-8 has established itself as the most common encoding for characters. But you can also use UTF-32 or others as long as you use the same encoding for both sending (encoding) and receiving (decoding).

For more information I recommend to read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: Oh thank you man! If i wanted to send an image through sockets, would i have to but it into binary format first? So i wouldn't have to encode/decode using base64 or UTF-8, i can just send it as binary on the socket?

Comment: @EesaMunir: If you already have the image as bytes (as you get from reading the image file) there is no need to encode it to base64 first. Sockets can transfer binary data.

Comment: Thank you man! So if i read the file, would it be turned into binary data and then that would be able to be sent on the socket? And also when the socket has been sent and received, will i have to turn the binary data(the image) back from binary to a raw file?

Comment: @EesaMunir: if you `f=open(name,"rb")` the file it will return a byte sequence if you `f.read(...)` it. This can be directly used for sending with the socket without any encoding. It can also be received this way and written into a file opened with `open(name,"wb")`.

Comment: Ah ok thank you. So when being sent, for turning it into binary you use .read, and when received, use open?

Comment: @EesaMunir: `read` is used for reading data and `open` is used for opening a file, which then can be read or written later. If the data are handled as bytes depending on the mode used with `open` - please look at the documentation for more. But all of this has nothing to do anymore with your original question which focused only on sockets and utf-8. So please stay within the context of your original question and ask new questions as needed. But I really recommend you to have a closer look at the Python documentation.

Comment: @EesaMunir looks like this fully answers your original question. Would be awesome to mark it accepted. Have a nice day.